# finding 'correlation' between two word lists

Tags: algorithm, similarity, information-retrieval

I have a list of words L1, and have candidate lists like B1, B2..,Bn all the lists are of the same length.  But they don't have the same elements. Lists doesn't contain repeated elements. L1 is most similar to only one of B1,B2...Bn. what kind of algorithms that I can apply to find the most correlated list to L1?

Some potential algorithms are edit distances, rank correlation (which should have same elements on both lists which is not the case in mine), dice and jaccard. I'm also not sure of the word 'correlation' here is it valid in this case?

**EDIT**: I have a set of documents and 2 topic modelling algorithms A1 and A2. I get 10 topics by applying A1 onto the set of documents and another 10 topics by applying A2. So the above lists define the words in these topics. So now I want to find similar topics created by these 2 algorithms A1 and A2.

Comment: You want to determine which of B1,B2,...Bn is *most similar to* L1? You have to first define what you mean by similar. Does it mean that you compare B1[0] and L1[0], then B2[0] and L1[0], etc? Or do you compare B1[0] against all elements in L1, B1[1] against all elements, etc. You have to provide more information about what it means for lists to be similar before we can suggest ways to compute it.

Comment: The edit is marginally helpful. Can you give us some sample data, like the lists of topics identified by algorithms A1 and A2? And what are your expectations? Do you expect that your similarity algorithm would be able to tell that "wood carving" and "whittling" are closely related, and that "fundamental rights" and "fundamentalist rites" are completely unrelated?

Comment: I got it solved using Dice and Jaccard. thanks a lot for trying to help me!

Comment: Hi KillBill, this is exactly what I'm looking for too. Care to give some more hints or resources regarding your solution?

Comment: you can try calculating jaccard or dice similatity scores between each pair of lists and then pick the list with the highest similatity score to the original list as the most similar list to the original list. is this helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to start with the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: I'm sorry.. I've had a misunderstanding, reading too quickly your question.. try posting a list examples of the words to be compared for better understanding